# What does the C3 portion of 0xC308(BE) mean in an ICMP identifier?

Tags: wireshark, icmp, hexidecimal

I am using Wireshark to analyze traffic. I know that the 8 refers to the echo (ping) type. I have been unsuccesful with finding information regarding the C3 byte.

```
Identifier (BE): 49928 (0xc308)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look it up in [rfc792](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/rfc/rfc792.txt) (page 13):
Identifier
If code = 0, an identifier to aid in matching echos and replies, may be zero.
Here is another usefull link:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xml